# How do I know if the user selected a SharePoint file in OpenFileDialog?

Tags: sharepoint, openfiledialog, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

In an OpenFileDialog, the user can enter the address of the SharePoint site and select a document in the document library. 
I need to provide check-in/check-out integration for SharePoint documents. Is there any way to determine if the file is stored in a SharePoint document library?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the dialog returns, you can check the value of the selected file.  If there's a value, they probably selected a file.  You can validate that a file was actually selected by attempting to open the file.

Start here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx

Comment: How does knowing that a file is selected help me figure out if the file is stored in a SharePoint site?

Comment: Once you have a URI value, you can strip off the document name and attempt to open a SPSite object.  If it succeeds, your document is stored in a SharePoint site.  Try this:

Comment: using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://YOUR_URL_HERE"))
{
    if (site != null)
    {
        //Process check in/out
    }
    else
    {
        //Not a SharePoint site.
    }
}

The trick is that the SPSite object is smart enough to deduce if your URL contains a valid path to a SharePoint site collection at it's beginning.  If it does, it'll create the object.  If not, you're not in SharePoint.